# Http-source flume into hdfs is not working​.? The status code for the post request is 400?

Tags: api, hdfs, http-status-codes, flume, flume-ng

While setting an http-source for a flume agent, i used the port 8989. and the agent starts fine but when i make a post request i get the status_code 400 and on get request status_code is 400. Someone pointed out that i am passing wrong data in the post request. How can i know why type of data should i pass. Also i dont pass any data in get. Still it gives status_code 500.

```
`>>> res=requests.get('http://hdp.localdomain:41414')
>>> res.status_code
500
>>>
>>> res=requests.post('http://hdp.localdomain:41414',data=a)
>>> res.status_code
400
>>>
a ={
    "colorsArray":[{
            "colorName":"red",
            "hexValue":"#f00"
        },
        {
            "colorName":"green",
            "hexValue":"#0f0"
        },
        {
            "colorName":"blue",
            "hexValue":"#00f"
        }

    ]
}
`
```

a contains simple json data. Also the flume http-source seems working. Since no error in log.

Answer (score 0):

Send the data in this format

{
  "headers" : {
             "timestamp" : "434324343",
             "host" : "random_host.example.com"
             },
  "body" : "random_body"
  }

Comment: Yes that is correct. I found it lately. How  the headers key work? I know only the body is saved as a file in hdfs. Can we use the headers once the body data is in hdfs in some file.